# How does FluentValidator determine what display name to use by default?

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, fluentvalidation, fluentvalidation-2.0

I'm working with FluentValidator in .NET Core.  Everything is working beautifully for the most part, but I notice that when working with complex types, FluentValidator shows the full property name. For example, let's say I have a class named Address with Street, City, State, and Zip properties.  Now let's say I have a form backed by a model property named Physical Address.  If I make the street required, Fluent shows the following validation error:

`'Physical Address. Street' must not be empty.`

I prefer this to it just saying "Street" must not be empty because I might have multiple address fields on the page, so just displaying "Street" isn't specific enough.  But I'd rather have it say:

`'Physical Address Street' must not be empty.` (with no period after the word address)

The example given by FluentValidation to globally override the display name is adding this in Startup.cs:

```
ValidatorOptions.DisplayNameResolver = (type, member, expression) => {
  if(member != null) {
     return member.Name + "Foo";
  }
  return null;
};
```

The override example works, but using this (minus the foo part) displays this validation error:

`'Street' must not be empty.` (the very thing I don't want because it's too generic)

What I need to know is what logic inside the lambda would produce the exact same result as the default behavior (i.e. **Physical Address. Street**, not just **Street**).  Once I know that, I can fix removing the period with a simple `defaultValue.Replace(".","")`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Much easier approach is to use `ValidatorOptions.Global.PropertyNameResolver`

```
ValidatorOptions.Global.DisplayNameResolver = (type, memberInfo, expression) =>
    ValidatorOptions.Global.PropertyNameResolver(type, memberInfo, expression).SplitPascalCase();
```

**Original Answer:**

Prepared complete demo based on [github sources](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/bbdacbd64fbd4e37ac9707d421e3327caa7c3b6f/src/FluentValidation/ValidatorOptions.cs)

Note: I am using `ValidatorOptions.Global.DisplayNameResolver` instead of `ValidatorOptions.DisplayNameResolver` since it is obsolete and will be removed in future versions

```
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.Internal;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public class Root
    {
        public PhysicalAddress PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
            = new PhysicalAddress();
    }

    public class PhysicalAddress
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootValidator : AbstractValidator<Root>
    {
        public RootValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.PhysicalAddress.Street).NotNull();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static string DefaultPropertyNameResolver(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo, LambdaExpression expression)
        {
            if (expression != null)
            {
                var chain = PropertyChain.FromExpression(expression);
                if (chain.Count > 0) return chain.ToString();
            }

            return memberInfo?.Name;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ValidatorOptions.Global.DisplayNameResolver = (type, memberInfo, expression) => 
                DefaultPropertyNameResolver(type, memberInfo, expression).SplitPascalCase();

            var res = new RootValidator().Validate(new Root());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it all right.  I went with the short-hand solution as it was indeed easier and I like to keep my code short and clean where possible :)  Thanks!